# WSL2, Ubuntu 20.04 - login issue

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, xrdp

it might be the case this has been answered before, but I was not yet able to find it.

Environment information:

- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS via WSL2
- Windows 10 (2004, 19041.508)
- fully upgraded
- network connectivity in place
- xrdp and mate-desktop installed

**Issue**
When I connect to 127.0.0.1:xrdp_port I get the login screen presented, as follow:
[loginscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xidba.png).
Within the xrdp config I added the username, so I don't have to bother always writing my login user. The issue then is, when pushing "Ok" within the log in screen, the connection drops without any message.

Snipped from xrdp.log

```
[20200924-09:39:41] [INFO ] Socket 11: AF_INET6 connection received from ::1 port 61498
[20200924-09:39:41] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 3399)
[20200924-09:39:41] [DEBUG] Closed socket 10 (AF_INET6 :: port 3399)
[20200924-09:39:41] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20200924-09:39:41] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20200924-09:39:41] [DEBUG] TLSv1.3 enabled
[20200924-09:39:41] [DEBUG] TLSv1.2 enabled
[20200924-09:39:41] [DEBUG] Security layer: requested 11, selected 1
[20200924-09:39:41] [INFO ] connected client computer name: SURFACEONE
[20200924-09:39:41] [INFO ] adding channel item name rdpdr chan_id 1004 flags 0x80800000
[20200924-09:39:41] [INFO ] adding channel item name rdpsnd chan_id 1005 flags 0xc0000000
[20200924-09:39:41] [INFO ] adding channel item name cliprdr chan_id 1006 flags 0xc0a00000
[20200924-09:39:41] [INFO ] adding channel item name drdynvc chan_id 1007 flags 0xc0800000
[20200924-09:39:41] [INFO ] TLS connection established from ::1 port 61498: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
[20200924-09:39:41] [DEBUG] xrdp_00000141_wm_login_mode_event_00000001
[20200924-09:39:41] [INFO ] Loading keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000407.ini
[20200924-09:39:41] [WARN ] local keymap file for 0x00000407 found and doesn't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
[20200924-09:42:30] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
[20200924-09:42:30] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
[20200924-09:42:30] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sending login info to session manager, please wait...
[20200924-09:42:30] [DEBUG] return value from xrdp_mm_connect 0
[20200924-09:42:30] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login successful for display 10
[20200924-09:42:30] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: started connecting
[20200924-09:42:31] [INFO ] lib_mod_log_peer: xrdp_pid=321 connected to X11rdp_pid=324 X11rdp_uid=1000 X11rdp_gid=1000 client_ip=::1 client_port=61498
[20200924-09:42:31] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connected ok
[20200924-09:42:31] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_connect_chansrv: chansrv connect successful
[20200924-09:42:31] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 61560)
[20200924-09:42:36] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 3399)
[20200924-09:42:36] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
[20200924-09:42:36] [DEBUG] Closed socket 18 (AF_UNIX)
[20200924-09:42:36] [DEBUG] Closed socket 19 (AF_UNIX)
```

snippet from xrdp-sesman.log

```
[20200924-09:42:30] [INFO ] A connection received from ::1 port 61560
[20200924-09:42:30] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username wslubuntu, ip ::1:61498 - socket: 11
[20200924-09:42:30] [INFO ] starting Xorg session...
[20200924-09:42:30] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET6 :: port 5910)
[20200924-09:42:30] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET6 :: port 6010)
[20200924-09:42:30] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET6 :: port 6210)
[20200924-09:42:30] [DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 3350)
[20200924-09:42:30] [INFO ] calling auth_start_session from pid 322
[20200924-09:42:30] [DEBUG] Closed socket 6 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 3350)
[20200924-09:42:30] [DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 3350)
[20200924-09:42:30] [INFO ] /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :10 -auth .Xauthority -config xrdp/xorg.conf -noreset -nolisten tcp -logfile .xorgxrdp.%s.log
[20200924-09:42:31] [CORE ] waiting for window manager (pid 323) to exit
[20200924-09:42:36] [CORE ] window manager (pid 323) did exit, cleaning up session
[20200924-09:42:36] [INFO ] calling auth_stop_session and auth_end from pid 322
[20200924-09:42:36] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets:
[20200924-09:42:36] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /run/xrdp/sockdir/xrdp_chansrv_audio_out_socket_10
[20200924-09:42:36] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /run/xrdp/sockdir/xrdp_chansrv_audio_in_socket_10
[20200924-09:42:36] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /run/xrdp/sockdir/xrdpapi_10
[20200924-09:42:36] [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username wslubuntu, display :10.0, session_pid 322, ip ::1:61498 - socket: 11
```

I hope you have some ideas on what's wrong on my end.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it now on my own, by installing mate-core.